# Session Component - Redis

Tags: session

When you configure the session component, I see `as session` used, pointing to the `SessionBehaviour` class but what does this do or what does it mean?

```
'session' => [
     'class' => yii\redis\Session::class,
     'as session' => craft\behaviors\SessionBehavior::class,
     'redis' => 'redis',
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Yii-ism, and part of its [dependency injection](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-di-container) or [configuration](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-configurations) system, which allows you to dynamically define [components](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-components) (like `session` or `db`). Part of that system involves [attaching Behaviors](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-behaviors#attaching-behaviors)—in this case, it's declaring the Craft-provided `SessionBehavior` be attached as `session`.

> The name is a little confusing, and isn't strictly necessary within the Behaviors system—named behaviors are just easier to detach or access directly, later on. It also appears as though they're required for the `as name` configuration shorthand!

Behaviors are sort of like [PHP's `trait` feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), except that they can be attached at runtime—in this case, when a property or method is unavailable on the configured `Session` component, Yii will comb through any attached Behaviors and look for that same property/method.

This lets Craft inject the [extra Session features it depends on](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/behaviors/SessionBehavior.php), without having to "own" a version of every Yii-compatible Session driver class. Instead, it just keeps those extra features in the `SessionBehavior` and bolts it on when the app is bootstrapped. You can see the default configuration [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/9a96dc7628ff7a8e77f86d731b6cc021a47aa3a3/src/helpers/App.php#L861-L879), which includes the same `as session` key and `SessionBehavior` class.

> Craft actually shims this feature for a few classes that aren't configured or mounted as "components" by providing `EVENT_DEFINE_BEHAVIORS` to let developers attach extra features.